# Display WordPress comments before the plugins?

Tags: plugins, customization, themes, comments

I am so happy that I found this site =)

Well, here is my problem:

I want to display the wp comments right after the post, but before the plugins content.

What I have tried so far:

in single-products.php file, the original code is:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>'.__('Pages','eStore').':</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>
<?php edit_post_link(__('Edit this page','eStore')); ?>
```

I tried put the comments(comments_template()) before and after the "the_content()", but its not correct. If I put:

- Before the_content(), it displays the comments section before the real content
- After the_content(), the comments are displayed below others plugin (simple social and Five rate stars plugins)

Is there anyway to insert in between them, I mean, between the post and plugins?

FYI: The theme that I am using, didnt display comment, so I have to display/enable it by myself. I am using wp 3.0.1

Plugin I am using:

- Plugin Name: Five Star Rating (http://fsr.dingobytes.com)
- Plugin Name: Simple Social - Sharing Widgets & Icons (Version: 0.2)

Comment: what plugins are you referring to?

Comment: Hi sorich: five-star rating and the simple-social plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [Five Star Rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/five-star-rating/), [the FAQ tells me](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/five-star-rating/faq/) you can leave out the shortcode from your articles (you added these to each article?), and then use `echo five_star_rating_func('star')` somewhere in your template. So this is a nice example of a plugin that offers both options.

For [Simple Social](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-social-sharing-widgets-icons/), you need to disable [the regular hook to `the_content`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/simple-social-sharing-widgets-icons/tags/0.2/simple-social.php#L135), and then call the function yourself. That could be done with the following code, which you can place in your theme's `functions.php` (or at the top of your `single.php`, if you only want it gone on single pages):

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'simple_social');
```

Then, to display it again where you want it, you call `simple_social()` with an empty content string (be sure to do this in The Loop, since it relies on the global `$post` variable):

```
echo simple_social('');
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand *plugins* you refer to add their output to the output of `the_content()` function. You can use `the_content` filter to achieve similar result in general.

But because it is filter - result is meant to be appended or otherwise included in data being passed, it's not a good place to load templates.

I think best way to approach this would be to disable plugins appending themselves to content (usually they have such option, they kinda should) and call them directly in template. That way you will be able to load comments template without issues and put it in order you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. How do I call the plugins manually in php code?

Comment: @wordpress_best: This depends on the plugin, you should take a look at the code. Plugins can hook in multiple places, but most of them will use `the_content`, and thus use `add_filter('the_content', [plugin function name])`. If you tell us what plugins you use (edit your question to add it), we could give more specific information.